# ActionController sessions and subclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, before-filter

By default all rails controllers inherit the application controller.

In my application I want users to be able to authenticate from any page using http-basic auth, and also authenticate by posting, but only to one controller.

Currently things look like this (simplified):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :set_current_user

    private

    def set_current_user
        Authorization.current_user = current_user
    end

    def current_user
        if session[:user].blank?
            authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |user,pass|
                session[:user] = authenticated_user_or_nil
            end
        end
        session[:user]
    end
end

class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
    prepend_before_filter :set_user_from_params

    private

    def set_user_from_params
        session[:user] = authenticated_user_or_nil
    end
end
```

I set a breakpoint in both `set_user_from_params` and `set_current_user` and have verified they are indeed being called in the correct order.

`set_user_from_params` is in fact setting `session[:user]` correctly, but when I continue and hit the breakpoint inside `set_current_user` the session hash is empty!?

Is this intended behaviour or have I missed something really obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the request is a post request then, by default rails will check for the presence of a valid csrf token.

A `before_filter` is inserted that does that check, if it fails then rails resets the session, which is consistent with your situation.

You need to either ensure that your post request contains an authenticity token or (if appropriate) disable that check by skipping the `verify_authenticity_token` filter.

One way of verifying that is to add

def handle_unverified_request
     super
     Rails.logger.info "handling unverified request - csrf issue"
   end

to your controller. If the issue is a csrf issue then this method will be called and will write to the log file confirming this has happened.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! In my case the auth is coming from an app that won't have a session or token yet.  For anyone else with this, I simply added `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create` to the controller in question.